# Load WebPage as in a Browser, but with Ruby

Tags: html, ruby, mathjax

hard to explain what I want to achieve, let me try:
I am using MathJax to render some Tex Code from a static HTML File. Now I want to "pre-render" the file(as in opening the file, let all the Mathjax process the document & create the needed styles and tags). i.e. I want the generated HTML file after I opened it, let's say in a browser

Purpose: If I save the rendered HTML document, I can easily open it up again and show it almost without processing to the user - almost instant.

Problem is, I have many many HTML Files and they all need to be processed, so I thought of ruby as my favorite scripting language to automate this. I looked into the mechanize gem, but it only seems to accept absolute URL's and I am not sure if this is what I really need.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this locally?

A million thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured it out by myself. 
I took a look into the gem selenium-webdriver and my code is following:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
...    
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.navigate.to "file:///Users/.../001.html"
sleep 2.0
html = driver.execute_script("return document.firstChild.innerHTML")
driver.quit
```